# If a link tag is injected into an iframe, where does the request come from?

Tags: jquery, iframe, code-injection

I have an iframe of a website (that I do not own) on my web page. I'd like to customise the style of the iframe's content.

I can do this with jQuery by injecting CSS like this:

```
jQuery("iframe#ID").contents().find('body').append('<style></style>');
```

My question is, if I then inject an embedded embedded font, like so:

```
jQuery("iframe#ID").contents().find('head').append('<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">');
```

does Google now think that the owner of the website in the iframe is requesting their font? Or will my website (the website containing the iframe) be requesting their font in this instance?

Comment: You can't access inside a cross origin iframe due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: I forgot to say that in this situation the same origin policy is bypassed.

Comment: bypassed how?... As for requester it will be the domain in the iframe